# Tricky Expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X$ denote a Poisson distributed random variable and let $Z = \max(X-\min(X,c),0)$, where $c$ is a constant. How do I compute $\mathbb E[Z]$?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The maximum is not useful.

Comment: @Did You mean to say: if $X$ ~ Poisson($\lambda$), then $E$[max($X$ $-$ min(.), 0)] = $\lambda$ $-$ $E$[min(.)] ?

Comment: @wolfies Sorry? Where do you see such a statement? No I do not "mean to say" that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $Z=(X-c)\mathbb{1}_{\{X\geq c\}}$.

Comment: Got it - many thanks!

Comment: So what solution did you get?

Comment: I applied the law of the unconscious statistician to obtain $\sum_{x=c}^{+\infty}(x-c)\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: Looks good, though that result assumes $c > 0$. For $c < 0$, it is just $\lambda - c$. The sum has a 'closed form' solution in terms of the incomplete Gamma function ... just pop it into a computer algebra system if desired.